# GNU screen: no output returned

Tags: shell, output, gnu-screen

When i re-attach to an existing/running window, the screen doesn't seem to be responding.
I can key in the input but no output displayed on the screen. When i do screen -ls, the screen and the socket is still there.
Anyone has any idea what could have probably happened prior to this? I could only restore the functionality by rebooting the server. Not sure if something has been broken between the screen and shell due to bad characters.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen -- typically when I foolishly suspended output to my terminal (like when I fat finger and hit CTRL-S or some other nonsense). We leave quite a few processes running in screen, so it's always a panic moment when we get a hung screen session.

The solution is to identify the `sshd` session associated with screen, and kill it.  This will free the screen and allow you to re-attach from another ssh session.  (note: be careful to NOT kill the main sshd or you may not be able to login remotely).

I find `pstree -ac` invaluable in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

If the command that you run for the screen **will terminate soon**, the screen will show as blank and not show the output.

But if you run command like `top` `python3 -m http.server` `nano *` that will not terminate soon, the screen will show.

### EDIT

To solve this problem, you can run `exec echo "hello world"` after create screen.